# List of clientIds of active users with Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm looking for a way to get the list of client ids of users that are currently on the website. Realtime reporting API seems to be giving just the metrics like the number of currently active users.

Is there any way to get actual client ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot get that information with the Realtime Reporting API. Here is a list of all the dimensions and metrics that API allows you to query:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/

To expand on this a bit, none of the reporting APIs give you access to the client ID. You can, however, store the client ID in a custom dimension and send that along with all your hits. This will give you access to the client ID through the Core Reporting API, but it still won't give you access through the Realtime Reporting API.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Philip! So basically, there is no way of getting client IDs of active users, right? Because Core Reporting API doesn't allow to access realtime user info, only the past info, correct?

Comment: That's correct. Maybe it will be added to a future version of the API, but it's not possible now.